# Spree Gem 1.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

- Mac OSX
- Rails 3.2.1
- Ruby 1.9.3p0

The spree documentation says to run gem install spree. This installs spree '0.70.3'. However, their documentation specifies spree '1.0.0' as the latest gem version.

When I add gem 'spree', '1.0.0' to my Gemfile and run bundle, it says "Could not find gem 'spree (= 1.0.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile."

When I run gem install spree -v '1.0.0' it says "Could not find a valid gem 'spree' (= 1.0.0) in any repository".

How do I install spree '1.0.0'?

Answer (score 0):

The command line is [here for Spree 1.0.0.rc4](https://rubygems.org/gems/spree/versions/1.0.0.rc4)

```
gem install spree --pre
```

Comment: In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (3.2.1)

  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 1.0.0.rc4) ruby depends on
      rails (<= 3.1.3, >= 3.1.1) ruby


When I edit my rails version in the GemFile, it complains about my jquery-rails version in Gemfile.lock.

When I edit that, it complains about something else...